# How could Wolverine's claws shape change during bone to adamantium blade transformation?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, x-men-cinematic-universe

Wolverine's original (initial) claws are made of bone:

[image]

They then get infused (like the rest of his bones) with adamantium, to become blades:

[image]

**Why would boned, irregular, cylindrical claws turn into thin blades?** (as opposed to still look like bones, just covered/infused with adamantium)

Comment: Because blades are **way cooler** and claws can't slice like a blade only scratch.

Comment: @WoJ no we don't do that to cross site duplicate and that edit was unnecessary

Comment: @AnkitSharma: I am not sure to understand why a link to an answer elsewhere is a bad thing but anyway.

Comment: @WoJ then you misunderstood it, link which can answer the question is better to be part of an answer or comment as pauline did, not inside the question itself.

Comment: Blades start thick and get thinner at the blade's cutting edge. The cylindrical bone shape may very well be in the thick section of the blade, holding the cutting edge. So, the  blade shape could be molded on top of the bone. This was always my head canon, so I never questioned it further. and wolverine blades are thick. The bone version do have a blade-like shape anyhow, as we can see in this closer shot.
https://static.comicvine.com/uploads/original/11119/111190794/4693350-3610849665-wolve.jpg

Comment: @CyberClaw: ah yes, you are right. I always saw them as cylindrical (probably from X-Men Origins: Wolverine where I thought I saw them as such when Victor broke them)

Comment: also they were supposed to be a lot shorter in Wolverine Origins as compared to DOFP. Looks like a visual mistake in the movies then ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per an answer on our [**sister site - Science Fiction & Fantasy**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5388/why-were-wolverine-s-metal-blades-shaped-differently-than-his-bone-claws)

> This has been inconsistently displayed through the comics.
>
> I believe that, in the most recent canon I've read, Wolverine's claws are bone, laced with Adamantium like the rest of his skeleton. This makes sense (in the comic book usage of the term, at least) because if the claws weren't part of his original skeleton he wouldn't have had the musculature in place to extend or retract them.
>
> As for the appearance in Origins, I can't answer why they would appear rough. I would expect that any claws would be similar to a cat's - smooth on the sides. They wouldn't be curved, of course, as they have to be stored in the forearm while retracted. It's likely that the Adamantium bonding would fill and smooth out any irregularities as it plated the bones, which could account for the visual difference you point out.